# How can I get text from element with Selenium webdriver and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

[image]

My code:

```
        WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();

        driver.get("http://bet.hkjc.com/football/default.aspx");
        WebElement matchs = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.Head to Head"));

        System.out.println(matchs);

        driver.quit();
```

How can I crawl `Manchester Utd` **and** `Celta Vigo`?

Comment: I don't understand the font, can you please provide a snapshot of the element/link from which you want to get `Manchester Utd AND Celta Vigo`

Comment: http://bet.hkjc.com/football/default.aspx

Comment: I am looking for the HTML DOM of the element from where you want to extract text. I dont understand the font, so I want the pic/snapshot of that element/link so that I can find it on the website easily :)

Comment: @DnYk Is this still open?

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement matchs = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Head to Head']"));
System.out.println(matchs.getText());
```

Comment: cosole display : An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Comment: @DnYk try using firebug and firepath .its very easy

Answer (score 0):

Use `firebug` and `firepath` addons in `firefox` and inspect that element and get the xpath and put it here inside double quotes in this code :

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).getText());
```

If you don't know how to use firebug and firepath refer [this](http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) link

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the element either by css selector or xpath selector

By using xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Head to Head']"));
```

By using css Selector

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span > a[title='Head to Head']"));
```

OR Try somethings like this if not getting the match

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.cteams.ttgR2>span>a[title='Head to Head']"));
```

Note : in your code you are trying  like `span.Head to Head` in CSS selector `.` dot represents the class and according to your path  you are locating span tag which have class name "Head to Head" which doesn't exist in your dom as this is the title of anchor tag.

Went through the `Firebug` and `Firepath` plugins of Firefox initially to get the Xpath or css path

Explore some blogs to get clear understanding, you will be able to create by yourself

Refer This [link](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/css-selectors-tutorial-for-selenium-with-examples) for the same

Answer (score 0):

I assume all the above answers doesn't work for you and am providing another answer.

I can see both the texts are under "a" tag. So the idea is to navigate to the element and use **getText()** - which returns the visible text.

```
String word = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/a")).getText();
System.out.println(word);
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In all of my tests I'm using the getAttribute like this to get text and it is working fine for me on all drivers :

assertEquals(strCity, txtCity.getAttribute("value"));